# dyld: Library not loaded. when python exec an executable at the second time

Tags: python, macos, opencv, dyld

I'm using Python to exec an executable with OpenCV libraries:

```
if pid == 0:
    os.execv('ocr_process', ['ocr_process', filename, tmpOutputDir])
else:
    os.wait()
```

and it runs well at the first time by giving the expected output. At the second time, it throws a error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_objdetect.3.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jesse/Projects/SpyderProjects/ocr-entire/ocr_process
  Reason: image not found`

And this .dylib could be loaded since the executable runs well at the very first time.

Besides, if I restart Python interpreter , this executable could run well but only one time too.

Since I put this function in the Python web backend, the Python interpreter could not be restarted to fix the problem.

Could anyone solve this problem? Thanks very much!